# How to stop the graph execution or change control flow if the tf.cond check fails in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I am constructing a graph in which I need to check the shape of the input tensor. I tried to use **tf.cond** on the tensor's shape. But I found **tf.cond** expects **true_fn** and **false_fn** to return the same type outputs. My question is how I can stop the execution when the input shape check fails. In general, how can I change control flow in the graph execution stage? My code looks like below. Thanks.

```
 input_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(input_str, channels = 3)
 img_shape = tf.shape(input_img)
 valid_img = tf.cond(tf.not_equal(img_shape[2], 3), STOP, input_img)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [tf.Assert](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging/Assert) will suit. You can choose desired condition, and in base case it's used

```
with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assert_equal(a, b)]):
    c = some_func(a, b)
```

If condition isn't met, it throws `Condition x == y did not hold element-wise` error